# Is it possible to update games on Steam remotely?

Tags: steam

I know that [you can install games remotely](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/1025-BD94-12FC-3409), but I can't find a way to update games remotely. I guess it's because Steam has auto-update system, but I have disabled that in the past. Problem is, now that CoD: MW3 is getting released tomorrow, it seems to be requiring me to download 100GB of update file, according to my friend.

Someone on Steam states that [it can be done by using other PC](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/0/2577697615750144742/#c3047235828270826008), but I currently have no other PC besides my main rig. So I sought that if there is a way to update game on mobile app, but it doesn't seem to have a remote update system or such.

Is there nothing more we can do about it? Or is there any hidden another way?

Comment: Perhaps an indirect solution would be to use [Steam CMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) to perform the update by writing a shell or batch script ahead of time and schedule it to be executed at sometime after the update is available.

Comment: I hope I could use that solution but I'm away from my home for about 2 to 3 days or so... I think I will set that up when I get back to my home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Game updates can be downloaded through the steam [website](https://steamcommunity.com/my/games) or mobile app([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community), [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/steam-mobile/id495369748)) provided you are logged in and that your PC is turned on.

To do this:

1. Navigate to the "Library" section of the app.
2. Find the cover art for the game you wish to download/update and click/tap on that.
3. Open the "Remote Download" menu
4. Click/Tap the "play" button to begin the download.

Comment: While it may works on iOS, Android version doesn't seems to have the play button (image [here](https://i.gyazo.com/82457ff02f505a7b5b8bf6bce93b8651.png)). Thanks for the answer anyway. And welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Ah sorry, seems nearly identical to the iOS app as that's exactly where the update button is in mine. I'm surprised that this feature isn't present in both versions. I hope you can find some other workaround. And thanks!

Comment: You can also do this on the website, fyi.

Comment: FAQ page for @aytimothy suggestion: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/1025-BD94-12FC-3409.  Aytimothy, this is probably worth writing into an answer.

Comment: @Skye-AT The update button is there on my Android steam app.  It replaces the uninstall button on games for which an update is available.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That's pretty weird... the image I've shown is CoD's game page, so it should have that button if that's true, but I still don't see them. When I get home I'll check the games that have updates and see if I can find the button on the app.

Comment: @aytimothy Strange enough, the webpage solution that you suggested have led me to the conclusion that I wanted. While both answers are sure is a useful one, but: Clockwork's answer requires me to pair the phone and PC which needs my presence at home, (I can't do so since I'm out of home); And generalkenobi's answer... I honestly don't know why but it didn't work. If you wouldn't mind, could you write up an answer?

Comment: I didn't want to edit the answer because it "Clearly conflicts with author’s intent" and I felt it didn't warrant another answer @TimmyJim, and is a dupe of this answer.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Steam Link](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay#anywhere) for that purpose.

There's a mobile app version which allows you to remotely play the games installed on your computer from your phone, but I found out it could also be used as a remote desktop software, so you could also use it to manage Steam and update your games remotely.

The only inconvenient is you have to set it up at home prior to using it (I think it requires being on the same network as the computer). After that, as long as you can connect to your Steam account from the device which has Steam Link, you can control your computer remotely, as long as it's booted.

The following are all the available Steam Link apps/software you can find from above link, depending on the platform on which you want to install it, as of 10th November 2023:

- [iTunes link for iPhone, iPad, & Apple TV (11.0+)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/steam-link/id1246969117)
- [Google Play link for Android (5.0+) phone, tablet, & TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valvesoftware.steamlink)
- [Android APK for people without Google Play](https://media.steampowered.com/steamlink/android/latest/steamlink-android.apk)
- [Raspberry Pi 3, 3+, & 4](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/6/2806204039992195182/?snr=1_14_1581__1580)
- [Windows](https://media.steampowered.com/steamlink/windows/latest/SteamLink.zip)
- [Linux](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.valvesoftware.SteamLink)
- [MacOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/steam-link/id1246969117)

Comment: I stopped using AnyDesk and TeamViewer when I found out about this.

Comment: This at first looked like what I was looking for, but it required me to pair phone and PC, which requires my presence at home to do so (and it looked like phone should be in the same network as the PC), though this could be the answer when I paired them. Just one question: Does this work outside home, meaning outside of the home's network, such as mobile network, etc?

Comment: @Skye-AT I'm practically sure that, after pairing my phone with my PC's Steam account, I was able to connect using my phone's mobile data (and WiFi was turned off), but that was a few months ago, and I haven't retried since then. But yeah, if you're not at home to set it up, it's definitely less convenient than the web browser solution someone mentioned.

Comment: They reused the name for an app? That'd get confusing if you want to use that and also have the hardware steam link from years ago.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah, they did. I kept stumbling on the store page of the hardware, which was confusing when I was trying to learn more about the software.